# I am getting an error about red5 media server

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

When i write this

`svn checkout http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only`

it says

```
svn:E170000: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only doesn't exist
```

Please help to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

That commands looks OK.

As you got:

```
svn:E170000: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only doesn't exist
```

It means that svn command see **red5-read-only as part of repo URL**, otherwise, it would just say:

```
svn:E170000: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ doesn't exist
```

Try to carefully rewrite your command and make sure that your repo URL and *red5-read-only* directory are not concatenated.